# Stored procedure import data from view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, view

I'd like to do a sync job - from a view to different tables.
I'm having a DB view (from a linked server) and I'd like to make a stored procedure which splits the db view into 2 tables.
The db view looks like:

- person_id
- person_type (=> either 'employee' or 'customer')
- lastname
- firstname
- email

The tables are 'employees' and 'customers'. Both of them have at least the attributes 'lastname', 'firstname' and 'email'. 
If the data row already exists in the tables there will be an update otherwise an insert. The attribute 'person_type' is to decide witch table I have to use.

I use ms sql server 2008 r2.

Can anybody help me creating the stored procedure? Or give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 merge statements, one to perform each task.

One MERGE statement will insert/update/delete into the Employee table and the other will do the same to the Customer Table.

Example:

```
MERGE YourCustomerTable TargetTable
USING (SELECT * FROM YourView WHERE Column = 'Customer') SourceTable ON TargetTable.CustomerID = SourceTable.CustomerID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE...........
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ColumnA, ColumnB) Values (SourceTable.ColumnA, SourceTable.ColumnB)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understand that you need to create two tables for Customer and employee from DB view.

For making this fast; create a ssis package and use "Conditional Split" option to split the table based on the person_type column. and insert it ot corresponding table.

You can save this package and run it whenever u need or u can make it as a job